# Backbone.js model not defined in view?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I've decided that I am going to try and learn backbone.js by making a web app. This is the first time I have done anything extensive in javascript, so the answer to my problem may be right in front of my face.

I have the web app on [github](https://github.com/tominated/Vendotron), along with a [running version](http://tominated.github.com/Vendotron/) that doesn't work. The javascript console just says that something is undefined when I don't think it should be. Here's the error that chrome gives for line 30 of app.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined
```

I've sort of been referencing the [backbone-fundamentals](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals) example modular to-do app, and it doesn't seem to have any issues with a similar thing.

If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong, I would be most appreciative!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Machine view render method was missing `return this` and by default all methods return undefined - that's why chaining didn't work

Edit: and a small tip:

jQuery, Underscore and Backbone register globally - and thanks to that you don't have to define them as dependencies every time - it's enough if you require them in your main script once and after that you can access them from the global scope as you normally would

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was returning `this` without the `return` keyword. As i was using javascript and not coffeescript it failed on me. So, if you are using javascript use `return this;` instead of just `this` in the last line of the `render()` function.

I also had a problem when using `this.collection.on('reset', this.render(), this)`. I instead had to use `this.collection.on('reset', this.render.bind(this));`